# build a docker image for Rest API built with Scala Play

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt

I am trying to dockerize the Rest API built with Scala Play so I can use  AWS EC2 or Kubernetes to deploy it.

Following this:
:
https://guilhebl.github.io/scala/backend/docker/play/2017/08/23/scala-play-docker-sbt-native-packager-example/ and 
it failed using this sequence of command:

```
sbt playGenerateSecret
sbt dist
sbt docker:publishLocal
docker run -p 9000:9000 -e APPLICATION_SECRET="token from above"  play-scala-rest-api-example:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

with this official example app:

https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-rest-api-example

Other teams need a `Dockerfile` to deploy the app to AWS EC2 with Jenkins. Right now it seems like  a `Dockerfile` is not generated until `sbt docker:publishLocal`

It would be better if we can find some official tutorials showing how to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-rest-api-example seems official to me. it's under the play framework org on GitHub

Comment: You has changed the question including the error messages and the original ask without leaving any indication behind. Please do not do this if you appreciate the time others spent trying to help you out.

Comment: @dbaltor Thank you for your reminder. I modified the question a little bit with the intention mentioned in the modification log.

Comment: how does you Dockerfile look like?

Comment: can't you generate the secret once and put it in the conf file?

Comment: The problem using `sbt docker:publishLocal` in that tutorial is that there is no `Dockerfile` until you build it.

Comment: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#tasks

try `sbt docker:stage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from mfirry:

```
 sbt docker:stage
```

from https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#tasks